# Denclue 2.0 in R

Tags: r, statistics, cluster-analysis

Has anyone successfully implemented the Denclue 2.0 algorithm in R? (or Matlab)

I'm getting stuck converting the hill climbing to an EM version as outlined in the paper [here](http://www.sciweavers.org/publications/denclue-20-fast-clustering-based-kernel-density-estimation)

I've been able to construct the 1.0 Algorithm but am unsure of how to accomplish the next phase

Comment: As the DataMungerGuru says, "what is the problem you are trying to solve?"  I peeked at the paper, and it seems to give all the equations in the algorithms pretty explicitly. Perhaps you could post (a reference to) the formulas that are hanging you up, with a reproducible set of code, data, and the error message or 'bad' data you are getting back.

Comment: I did try the authors but had no response unfortunately.